# cocos2d particle system auto remove

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, particles

As far as I understand, autoRemoveOnFinish only works only when the duration has a finite value. But what if I stop the particle system at some point, will it remove the node after no particles left?
for example

```
CCParticleSun *particleSun = [CCParticleSun node];
particleSun.autoRemoveOnFinish = YES;
[self addChild: particleSun];
```

and at some point in the game I set

```
[particleSun stopSystem];
```

Will this remove the node after no particles left?
Thank you in advance for helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes.See the method `-(void) update: (ccTime) dt` in `CCParticleSystem.m`

```
    if( particleCount == 0 && autoRemoveOnFinish_ ) {
                [self unscheduleUpdate];
                [parent_ removeChild:self cleanup:YES];
                return;
            }
```

Try to set a breakpoint here to check,this will be called after no particles left.

Comment: You also helped me remove a bug. Thank you

Comment: @user1817517 Accept the answer to end this question please,so the answer can help people who have the same problem :)